# "Painting" with text, and finding the boundaries of rectangles

Tags: python

I am attempting to replicate a simple "painting" program using a list-based canvas comprised of dictionaries, which represent rectangles. I am **not** a good algorithmic programmer, so please, bear with me.

To begin, the canvas is 20 x 6 units.

Each "rectangle" dictionary has 4 coordinates.

```
{ 'x1': 1, 'x2': 10, 'y1': 1, 'y2': 3 }
```

I can determine if a rectangle's range of coordinates overlaps another's easy enough:

```
def determine_range_overlap(self, r1_min, r1_max, r2_min, r2_max):
    if (r1_min <= r2_max) and (r2_min <= r1_max):

        # get the coordinates that overlap
        coordinates = list(set.intersection(set(range(r1_min, r1_max + 1)), set(range(r2_min, r2_max + 1))))
        if coordinates:
            return coordinates[0], coordinates[-1]
    return None, None
```

but where I'm running into trouble is determining if rectangles with a single dimension, aka, a line, horizontal in this case:

```
{ 'x1': 10, 'x2': 20, 'y1': 3, 'y2': 3 }  # both y values are equal
```

intersect the edges of the canvas to create the *visual representation* of a rectangle. Example:

```
----------------------
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|1111111111          |
|         2          |
|         2          |
----------------------
```

### The Problem

I want to create a `fill` method that would add a "color" to each point in the rectangle the designated X, Y falls within.

In this case, if there is a visual rectangle, and someone clicks on the background, I need this outcome. "c" represents the color fill:

```
----------------------
|cccccccccccccccccccc|
|cccccccccccccccccccc|
|cccccccccccccccccccc|
|1111111111cccccccccc|
|         2cccccccccc|
|         2cccccccccc|
----------------------
```

I am currently keeping a list of each rectangle added to the canvas, but the logic for how to handle the case of lines that intersect and also touch the canvas edges escapes me.

If I have X,Y coordinates that represent each line, is it possible to determine which of those intersections creates a rectangle? That seems the most logical, but I'm not sure how to go about that. Can someone recommend an approach?

---

### Update

I have managed to find the intersections of all "lines" on the canvas as a list of `x,y` dicts. For example:

```
----------------------
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|1111111111          |
|         2          |
|         2          |
----------------------
```

Would return a list of "intersections" ordered `x, y` as:

```
[
    {'y': 1, 'x': 1},  # canvas top & left lines
    {'y': 4, 'x': 1},  # line 1111111111 & canvas left line
    {'y': 6, 'x': 1},  # canvas bottom & left lines
    {'y': 4, 'x': 6},  # lines 1111111111 & 22
    {'y': 6, 'x': 10}, # line 22 & canvas bottom line
    {'y': 1, 'x': 20}, # canvas top & right lines
    {'y': 6, 'x': 20}  # canvas bottom & right lines
]
```

How can I determine all possible rectangles from the intersections? Given the sample points, I need to arrive at two rectangles:

```
[
    {'x1': 1, 'y1': 1, 'x2': 20, 'y2': 20}, # canvas
    {'x1': 1, 'y1': 4, 'x2': 10, 'y2': 6}   # intersection of 1111111111, 22 and canvas
]
```

Comment: Do you always want your `fill` to be blocked by other rectangles? For instance, if you had a third rectangle that crossed under your `1` rectangle, should filling it's upper side leave the lower side unfilled?

Comment: If the `fill` starting `(x,y)` were contained in the background, and there was a rectangle that overlapped the lines `1` and `2`, the rectangle would **not** be filled.

Comment: However, if the starting `(x,y)` is in a rectangle other than the background, it should only fill that rectangle.

Comment: I have managed to get a list of intersecting points from all of the lines, using the edges of the canvas as lines, plus whatever other lines I add. Now I just have to determine if I can create rectangles from any/all of those given `(x,y)` coordinates.

Comment: My point is, if you have two crossing rectangles (so that the one on the bottom is split in half by the one on the top), should the fill cover both parts of the one on the bottom, if the start position is on one of the sides?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes. What I'm attempting to do is examine the intersections and generate all possible rectangles from the points.